# New to reporting with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am getting to reporting with C# and Visual Studio 2010 for the first time. Most of my applications are win forms apps drivin by sql server data. What should I use to get started with reporting? I see there is a built in report designer in the toolbox and also a way to add reports at the project level. This includes some sort of built in report designer and a report wizard. Also I noticed a reporting designer called Crystal reports.

Is there a good direction I should go? Also any tips to get me started so I do not waste a lot of time?

Any help or direction would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for Crystal Reports, Its a well known reporting tool and you will find a lot of resources on the net about it. In addition to that, It is totally Free. 
Check these for more details:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287920%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225615%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wud4VtqpetU